# How do I wait for a message to be sent in a channel with DiscordJS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making an application bot and it will have options for multiple choice and short/long responses. The responses system uses direct messages and needs to wait for a message to be sent before continuing, but MessageChannel#awaitMessages isn't working for me. Here is my code (two separate parts):

```
// borrowed from another stackoverflow question
const waitUntil = (condition, checkInterval = 100) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (!condition()) return;
      clearInterval(interval);
      resolve();
    }, checkInterval)
  })
}
```

```
let shouldStop = false
var content = 1
var contentArrived = false
const filter = (m) => m.author.id == userId // userId is the ID of the user in DMs
interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, maxProcessed: 1, idle: 10_000, errors: ['idle'] })
    .then(collected => {
          console.log(`${collected.size} is pain and suffering`)
          content = collected.first().content
          contentArrived = true
     })
     .catch(() => {
          message.channel.send('You did not respond to the question so your application was canceled.')
          shouldStop = true
          currentlyApplying.set(userId, null)
     })
await waitUntil(() => {
    return contentArrived || shouldStop
}, 500)
```

I tried with awaitMessages with examples from the documentation and from other StackOverflow questions, and none of them worked. They all simply got stuck and did not detect any message, even though the filter was set to detect all non-bot messages. They would all then throw an error and be caught by the `.catch()`.

Comment: What were the errors that were caught? If it's just your generic message (`You did not respond ...` etc), change your `.catch(() => ...` to `.catch((err) => ...` and in inside the function, replace your current message with the value of `err`, just so you could see what went wrong. Perhaps the timeout will be triggered, and you'll see that error in the `catch((err) => ...` part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to include the `message` partial and enable the `DirectMessages` Intent when creating the Client.